# why isn't the rest of my method being called? (loop being ignored)

Tags: java, methods, substring, filereader

i'm trying to write a program that reads a file and then prints it out and then reads it again but only prints out the lines that begin with "The " the second time around. it DOES print out the contents of the file, but then it doesn't print out the lines that begin with "The " and i can't figure out why. it prints out the println line right before the loop, but then it ignores the for-loop completely. the only difference between my findThe method and my OutputTheArray method is the substring part, so i think that's the problem area but i don't know how to fix it.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class EZD_readingFiles
{

 public static int inputToArray(String fr[], Scanner sf)
{
  int max = -1;
  while(sf.hasNext())
  {
    max++;
    fr[max] = sf.nextLine();
  }
  return max;
}

public static void findThe(String fr[], int max)
{
  System.out.println("\nHere are the lines that begin with \"The\": \n");

  for(int b = 0; b <= max; b++)
  {
    String s = fr[b].substring(0,4);

    if(s.equals("The "))
    {
      System.out.println(fr[b]);
    }  
  }
}

public static void OutputTheArray(String fr[], int max)
{
  System.out.println("Here is the original file: \n");
  for(int a = 0; a <= max; a++)
  {
    System.out.println(fr[a]);
  }
}


public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
  Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File("EZD_readme.txt"));

  String fr[] = new String[5];

  int y = EZD_readingFiles.inputToArray(fr,sf);
  EZD_readingFiles.OutputTheArray(fr,y);

  int z = EZD_readingFiles.inputToArray(fr,sf);
  EZD_readingFiles.findThe(fr,z);
  sf.close();
 }
}
```

this is my text file with the tester data (EZD_readme.txt):

Every man tries as hard as he can.

The best way is this way.

The schedule is very good.

Cosmo Kramer is a doofus.

The best movie was cancelled.

Comment: You already read the entire file once, so the 2nd time you call inputToArray you have nothing to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try cloning sf and passing it to the other function.

Something like this:

```
Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File("EZD_readme.txt"));
Scanner sf1 = sf.clone();

int y = EZD_readingFiles.inputToArray(fr,sf);
EZD_readingFiles.OutputTheArray(fr,y);

int z = EZD_readingFiles.inputToArray(fr,sf1);
EZD_readingFiles.findThe(fr,z);
sf.close();
sf1.close();
```